# TraceSource in TestDriven.NET AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testdriven.net

I'm running tests using the TestDriven.NET VS add-in, and the class library I'm testing is instrumented using TraceSource.  How can I get the output of that TraceSource to show up in the Output window in Visual Studio?  The DefaultTraceListener doesn't appear to be working quite right.  Do I need to manually add a ConsoleListener or something (boy, would that be tedious with one TraceSource per class...)?

Comment: Are you running all tests in your library at once, or are you running just a single test(-function).  If the former, than Testdriver.NET will not show any output other than result summary.

Comment: I suppose I'm just running a single test.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Running all tests didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSDN documentation states:

> A DefaultTraceListener emits Write and
>   WriteLine messages to the
>   **OutputDebugString** and to the
>   Debugger.Log method. In Visual Studio,
>   this causes the debugging messages to
>   appear in the Output window. Fail and
>   failed Assert messages also emit to
>   the OutputDebugString Windows API and
>   the Debugger.Log method, and also
>   cause a message box to be displayed.
>   This behavior is the default behavior
>   for Debug and Trace messages, because
>   DefaultTraceListener is automatically
>   included in every Listeners collection
>   and is the only listener automatically
>   included. *(emphasis mine)*

I haven't used TestDrivent.NET so I wouldn't know why the trace output isn't appearing in your Output window, but you might be able to use [DbgView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) to view your output since it collects output written by OutputDebugString.